# Can't run composer update missing mbstring

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, composer-php, mbstring

I am trying to configure Linux Ubuntu 20.04 server to run laravel, and i have nginx, mysql php7.4-fpm installed, i cloned my project from gitlab and now i want to run composer update, but it always give me this error:

```
    composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v7.9.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.9.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.9.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.8.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.8.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.7.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.7.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.6.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.6.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.6.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.5.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.5.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.5.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.4.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.3.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.2.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.2.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.2.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.19.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.19.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.18.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.17.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.17.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.17.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.16.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.16.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.15.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.14.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.14.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.13.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.12.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.11.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.10.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.10.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.10.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.10.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.1.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.1.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.1.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.1.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.8 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.7 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.6 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.5 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.4 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.3 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.2 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.1 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v7.0.0 requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP exte                                        nsion mbstring is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 7.x-dev requires ext-mbstring * -> the requested PHP ext                                        ension mbstring is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/                                        framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.                                        7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.10.0, v7.10.1, v7.10.2, v7.10.3, v                                        7.11.0, v7.12.0, v7.13.0, v7.14.0, v7.14.1, v7.15.0, v7.16.0, v7.16.1, v7.17.0,                                         v7.17.1, v7.17.2, v7.18.0, v7.19.0, v7.19.1, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0, v7.                                        4.0, v7.5.0, v7.5.1, v7.5.2, v7.6.0, v7.6.1, v7.6.2, v7.7.0, v7.7.1, v7.8.0, v7.                                        8.1, v7.9.0, v7.9.1, v7.9.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PH                                        P in CLI mode.
```

When i run php --ini this is the output

```
administrator@orion:/var/www/truckstock$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.4/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

To fix the issue i tried installing php-mbstring using command sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring and this is the error that i am getting

```
administrator@orion:/etc/php/7.4/mods-available$ sudo apt install php7.4-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.4-mbstring : Depends: libonig5 (>= 6.8.1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
administrator@orion:/etc/php/7.4/mods-available$
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please add php version and composer version.

Comment: What keeps you from installing the missing dependencies?

Comment: php is 7.4 and it wont install php7.4-mbstring i am getting this error `php7.4-mbstring : Depends: libonig5 (>= 6.8.1) but it is not installable`

Comment: Please share more details. **Why'* is that package not installable? It should be, as it does not have a lot of dependencies, and it is available as v6.9.2 in Ubuntu 20.04. "You have held broken packages" sounds like a wider problem

Answer (score -1):

Here is the command you need to execute on your server

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-mbstring
```

Comment: So when i run that i php-mbstring gets installed but for the php7.2 `root@orion:~# apt install php-mbstring
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-mbstring is already the newest version (1:7.2+60ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 91 not upgraded.
root@orion:~#`

Comment: for 7.2, you have type ```sudo apt install php7.2-mbstring```

Comment: I need it to install it for php 7.4 adn when i try it says `
 php7.4-mbstring : Depends: libonig5 (>= 6.8.1) but it is not installable
`

Answer (score -1):

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libo/libonig/libonig5_6.9.4-1_amd64.deb

```
sudo dpkg -i libonig5_6.9.4-1_amd64.deb
```