# Ubuntu Creating Laravel Project Fails

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, ubuntu, composer-php

I'm trying to create a Laravel project on ubuntu => "XAMPP" installed => "PHP" 8.0.7 => "Composer" 2.0.1.

but I get this error :

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev] require ext-mbstring * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's mbstring extension.
- Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^8.40 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v8.40.0, ..., 8.x-dev].

```
'''
To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
'''
```

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62890944/cant-run-composer-update-missing-mbstring

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49087913/laravel-framework-requires-ext-mbstring

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891013/the-requested-php-extension-mbstring-is-missing-from-your-system

Comment: please do some research before asking a question.. so many questions exist already related to this topic.

Comment: Look Laravel doc : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-requirements

Comment: The answer which is marked in the question is belong to Windows OS! not Ubuntu OS! nice choice!

Comment: @AminEshtiaghi just choose any of the other answers I've listed

Comment: @NicoHaase , so based on the second one (which is not approved) and third one which you mentioned my answer is right, I want to know why you devote my answer? (which is right and it's against StackOverflow terms and conditions which I can pursue it).

Comment: What do you mean by "devote my answer"? What do you mean by "against StackOverflow terms and conditions"?

Comment: I haven't interacted with your answer in any way. Also, it's encouraged to mark a question as a duplicate if it was answered before on SO, instead of posting a new answer that contains merely the same information that is already present in another answer

Comment: I have tried all these methods and none of them worked , then I found this solution in a Youtube video and it worked, so I shared it.

Comment: @NicoHaase and also the answer I posted is not the same as the answers in these post you mentioned, Thank you but you should've checked first.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue before and seems yours is very similar which I had.
That's why the Ubuntu OS needs required PHP extensions as well.
you can install them by following command:

```sh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php php-cli php-fpm php-json php-common php-mysql php-zip php-gd php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath
```

Also, you can have a look at this article:
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-php-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution to the problem :

-first after installing XAMPP don't open it. if it's open close it using :

```
"sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop"
```

-then run the following comman :

```
"sudo gedit /etc/environment"
```

it will open a text editor modify its content to make like the image below:
[image]

by adding :
":/opt/lampp/bin/php"
to the end

-and then run the following command :

```
"sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/local/bin/php"
```

-finally start XAMPP using the following command:

```
"sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start"
```

Comment: Why did you install XAMPP, but not use it? This looks like a misconfiguration to me

Comment: @NicoHaase well that's is interesting,  would you mind to explain, please?